# Testify "with" someone

Tags: prepositions

> They've testified with me that the events of that evening followed according to my description.

Is "with" fine here? I can't think of any other preposition here, as the meaning essentially is "they agreed with me/supported my testimony."

Comment: I'd pay more attention to the choice of verb than the choice of preposition here. People usually only ***testify*** in legal courts. *They've **told me** that the events of that evening followed according to my description.* But if you insist on using the less common word, I'd say people usually testify ***to** [a courtroom]* (or they *testify **before** the court*). Note that people can also *testify **to the truth** of something* or (less commonly) *testify **to doing** [something*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers But it's not the meaning I need. I want to say that the testimonies they gave supported mine. They didn't tell me; they testified to a third party.

Comment: In that case, to make sure your meaning is crystal clear, I suggest the slight adjustment: *They've testified **along with** me that...* (or *alongside, together with*, or *in support of*, perhaps).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, "along with" seems to be the way out, thank you!

Comment: _They confirmed my statement_.